# Android ImageView setting source of image

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm trying to set the source of my image, but I get an error.

```java
String test1 = pref.getString("test", "ERROR");
String drawable1 = "R.drawable."+test1;
myImage.setImageResource(drawable1);
```

I've tried setting `int drawable1 = "R.drawable."+test1;`, but it still doesn't work. I know it's a mismatch of types, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get it done.

It seems you could break the problem down even further and say how do you make this work?

```java
String drawable1 = "R.drawable.myImage";
myImage.setImageResource(drawable1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yet another down vote. No comment. Seems legit.

Comment: Probably because this question has been asked before and therefore doesn't show research effort. (I am not the downvoter though, just guessing here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried setting `int drawable1 = "R.drawable."+test1;`, but it still doesn't work.

You need to use [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to properly build resource ids from Strings:

```
int drawable1 = getResources().getIdentifier(test1, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

(There are now two other answer that suggest this same thing... Did I miss something or did they just feel like repeating what's already been stated?)

---

As a note, if your Image is large or causes a noticable delay while loading the documentation on [`setImageResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) has alternate suggestions:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using `setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)` or `setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` and `BitmapFactory` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `context` (use `this` if the code is within an activity)

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(test1 , "drawable", cw.getPackageName());
myImage.setImageResource(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 int drawable1 =  getResources().getIdentifier(test1, "drawable", getPackageName();
```

To learn more how to Get Resources by Name see this [link](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html)